# Is there an interface for grouping all controls that CauseValidation?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm looking to find a common interface/base for all controls that implement a CausesValidation property.

I know that the IButtonControl, can be used for buttons, but other input controls - DropDownLists, TextBoxes etc need to be catered for too.

Does a common interface exist or is there an additional interface other than IButtonControl or do I have to resort to naming every control type?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this class

[ContainerControl.Validate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4wf8t2at%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: That's a method actually

Comment: he can use this work around put all his controls in container and then validate them. I think it will work.

Comment: @AftabAhmed - Except I'm not looking to validate them, just configure them